# C# Cannot Find Main Method

Tags: c#

I am currently learning C#.

```
public class Dude
{
    public void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    }

}
```

This code is generating this error:

> Cannot find Main method

A few notes:

1. I am aware that I can remove the class altogether and it will run.
2. I am trying to use a class, but it was not working, so I removed everything I had except for the above and I'm trying to troubleshoot it 1 line at a time.

**Edit:**

1. It seems to work when I don't put the void part in the class, hmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Main()` method is the entry point from where the execution starts and needs to be `static`. This allows the execution environment to call the function without having to instantiate an object/instance of a class

You can make the method static by adding the `static` keyword

```
public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Hi");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in addition to the above answer:

Since Main is the entry point to your program it should look like this

```
public static void Main()
```

But in the future its good practice to have it look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

This is because you can input parameters via the command line when running the program. They'll get placed into the args variable that you can then check for.

For example: my company uses a command parameter to allow us to access all modules of the product while we are testing it and developing new features. The Main method checks to see if this parameter is contained within the args variable and acts accordingly